# Looping over a fixed string or variable string in bash script

Tags: bash

I am new to bash scripting and have two loops as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

##########
# Loop 1 #
##########
for x in "one two three four";
do
    echo $x
done
```

Output:

```
one two three four
```

```
##########
# Loop 2 #
##########
var="one two three four"
for x in $var;
do
    echo $x
done
```

Output:

```
one
two
three
four
```

I am looking for pointers to help understand why the first loop `echo`s the string as is while the second one splits at whitespace and then `echo`s each split word.

EDIT: Rephrased the question for clarity.

Comment: Look up *word splitting*

Comment: To be complete, consider `for x in "$var";` and `for x in $(echo "one two three four");`

Comment: Also paste your script into [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net)

Comment: `for x in one two three four` is what you should be doing, if you want the loop to run once for each of `one`, `two`, `three` and `four`.

Comment: `for x in $var` is itself a bad practice -- the value in `var` is subject to not just string-splitting but also globbing. If you want to store a list of things, it should be stored in an array, not a string.

Comment: For clearer understanding of what's going on, look at `for x in "two words" "two more words"; do` -- given that loop definition, your code first runs `echo two words`, then `echo two more words`. If the shell didn't behave that way, its loops would be less powerful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fundamental misunderstanding here is as follows: The shell *doesn't* loop over strings; it only loops over lists of what it calls "words". When you perform an unquoted expansion (like `$var`), unless it's in a context that implicitly suppresses string splitting (also called "word splitting"), the contents of `$var` are split on characters in `IFS` (by default: tabs, spaces and newlines) to form a list of words, and then each of those words is expanded as a glob (so `*.txt` can be replaced with `a.txt` `b.txt` `c.txt` -- or `file one.txt`, for that matter, if a matching name containing spaces exists in the current directory).

In `for x in "one two three four"`, `one two three four` -- because it was quoted -- is a single word. By contrast, `for x in one two three four` or `for x in "one" "two" "three" "four"` would iterate over each of `one`, `two`, `three`, and `four` as a distinct word.

When you run `var="one two three four"; for x in $var`, then `$var` is -- because the expansion is unquoted -- split into multiple words, so `one` is a word, `two` a second one, `three` a third, `four` a fourth.

On the other hand, if you ran `for x in "$var"`, the quotes would suppress string splitting and globbing, so the inside of the loop would only run once, with the entire string held together.

---

The best practice is *not* to use `for x in $var` at all. When you want to have a list of things in bash, use an array to store that list.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^ - NOT sh, which doesn't support arrays

var=( "first word" "second word" )
for x in "${var[@]}"; do
  echo "$x"
done
```

Comment: `the contents of $var are split on characters in IFS (by default: tabs, spaces and newlines) to form a list of words` Is a list the same as an array in bash? If it is, when I do `var="one two three four"; x=$var; echo ${x[1]}`, I would expect to see "one". But it seems to be a null value.

Comment: @ethelion, when you run `var="one two three four"`, you set `var[0]` to `one two three four`. The entire string is in the 0th entry if you treat a string as if it were an array.

Comment: @ethelion, ...word-splitting doesn't happen automagically when you dereference a string as an array; it only happens during unquoted expansions in a context where it's not otherwise suppressed, and the right-hand side of an assignment to a string is a context where it _is_ suppressed.

Comment: @ethelion, ...now, if you _did_ want to use string-splitting to break your string into an array, that would be `array=( $var )`, after which `echo "${array[1]}"` will indeed output `two` (as the first item is in index 0, not index 1).

Comment: @ethelion, ...that said, `array=( $var )` is generally considered an antipattern -- see [BashPitfalls #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29). Typically `read -r -a array <<<"$var"` is a better choice, as it suppresses globbing and _only_ does splitting on characters in IFS; or `readarray -t array <<<"$var"` if you only want to split on newlines..

Comment: `right-hand side of an assignment to a string is a context where it is suppressed.` This information was particularly useful to understand what's going on. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

It is *very* hard to improve on Charles Duffy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68825208/298607) but let me offer a little different way of thinking about this.

Bash in general and in simple terms operates on the [syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Syntax.html#Shell-Syntax) of a [command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Commands.html) on targets. ie, what is the `action` (command) and what (if any) is the `target` of that action. The targets are *usually* [determined](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Operation.html#Shell-Operation) by [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html) which includes, in your case, [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html).

Shell expansions are contextual, but commonly when an **unquoted** string or variable is being prepared for an action such as

1. target of a loop;
2. assigned to an array with `( )`;
3. parsed as part of a command argument.

the strings are first subject to shell expansions.

Here is an example. Assume an empty directory:

```
bash-5.1$ ls       # ls is a COMMAND - in this case no targets
bash-5.1$ 
# no files....
```

Create some files with a COMMAND and an EXPANSION that expands to 3 files names (targets):

```
bash-5.1$ touch {1..3}.txt      
bash-5.1$ ls -1
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
```

Here we are using a [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) to expand into the three targets of `1.txt 2.txt 3.txt` as an argument to the command `touch`. (If you had `touch "{1..3}.txt"` a single file by that name would be created since there is no shell expansions on quoted strings.)

Now if we want to work with those three files, we would either glob for them (or create another form of *shell expansion* such as a brace expansion) or specify them as fixed strings:

```
# *.txt without quotes is a glob
bash-5.1$ for f in *.txt; do ls -l "$f"; done
-rw-r--r--  1 dawg  wheel  0 Aug 18 10:00 1.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 dawg  wheel  0 Aug 18 10:00 2.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 dawg  wheel  0 Aug 18 10:00 3.txt
```

Note that no longer works as expected if you add quotes around `*.txt`

```
# "*.txt" is just a string
bash-5.1$ for f in "*.txt"; do ls -l "$f"; done
ls: *.txt: No such file or directory
```

Or:

```
# three fixed strings with quotes
bash-5.1$ for f in "1.txt" "2.txt" "3.txt"; do ls -l "$f"; done
-rw-r--r--  1 dawg  wheel  0 Aug 18 10:00 1.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 dawg  wheel  0 Aug 18 10:00 2.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 dawg  wheel  0 Aug 18 10:00 3.txt
```

Now `1.txt 2.txt 3.txt` without quotes would produce the same result in this case since none of the file names have any characters that would be used for a shell expansion. (And you can have surprising and bad results if there **are** globs or other expansions in an unquoted string...)

But notice `"1.txt 2.txt 3.txt"` does NOT work since there is no `1.txt 2.txt 3.txt` file and strings in "quotes" are not subject to word splitting:

```
bash-5.1$ for f in "1.txt 2.txt 3.txt"; do ls -l "$f"; done
ls: 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt: No such file or directory
```

**Notice the use or nonuse of "quotes" that should become second nature to you or you will have much pain and suffering in the shell!**

---

So long story short: The output of your first loop is different than the second loop because quoted strings are not subject to shell expansions. Double quotes strings ARE subject to interpolation however and that is how `"$var"` *becomes* the single string contained in `$var`.

You can switch the output so the first loop is the same as the second with this:

```
for x in $(echo "one two three four"); # force a shell expansion
do
    echo $x
done
# prints
one
two
three
four
```

and the second will look like the first if you add quotes around `$var`:

```
var="one two three four"
for x in "$var";      # quoted is NOT subject to shell expansions
do
    echo $x
done
# prints
one two three four
```